# Populate Mongoose Array Subdocuments

Tags: mongoose

I have two schemas - Match and Member.  Match contains an array of Members.

```
var MatchSchema = new Schema({name: String, players: [{
    player: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Member'},
    play: Boolean}]});

var MemberSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String});
```

I'm trying to populate the the ObjectIds with per http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
.populate({
  path: 'players',
  populate: {path: 'player'}
})
```

Per Mongoose debug, the matches.find query returns the two expected Member ObjectIds, ...

```
Mongoose: matches.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5883a57362f0ca10945b305a") }, { fields: undefined })
Mongoose: matches.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("58502d28e88746467d48b424"), ObjectId("583c82ef5274831a5443fa53")] } }, { fields: undefined })
```

but `match.players.player` is not populated with `firstName` or `lastName`.

I believe that I've tried all of the combinations/options of population syntax.  Any ideas?

Comment: What did you console to get the result you have put in the question. I have not seen Mongoose giving result like this.

Comment: Simply add this code to your server -`mongoose.set('debug', true);`  May sure you are looking at the server console/terminal and not the client.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right path but doing one mistake in populate.

You should populate `players.player` instead of nested population( populating `players` and `player` inside that). `players` is not a reference, but an array, and `players.player` is  a reference, and that's why your method isn't working.

Try this:

```
.Populate('players.player')
```

This should work for you.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I'm in the process of restructuring my data to make server calls less complex.  Will advise if that works for me.

Comment: what is the error it is showing?, and what are the structural changes that you  are doing?

Comment: The same error as shown above `{fields: undefined}`.  I've eliminated the Object in the players array and just using an array of Member ObjectIds.

Comment: This doesn't work with a large quantity of populate() call

Comment: what do you mean by large quantities of `populate()` call? Can you show me your schema? or maybe you can create a new question and tell me the link here.